# Decompile and print object in python?

Tags: python

I am investigating one suspicious program we have been using for months. After some complex code it dynamically generates an object (type() get `<type 'code'>`) and then executes it with `exec`. This is where I got lost. I have a tool for decompiling whole pyc compiled file, but I don't know how to decompile a dynamically generated object within a running program.

I can print it (nice bytecode there), I can write it to file. I tried to write it to a file and running pyc decompiler on it, but since it was bytecode of just one object and not full valid pyc program, it failed

Comment: can you save the object somehow and decompyle after

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham: yes, I can print it (nice bytecode there), I can write it to file. I tried to write it to a file and running pyc decompiler on it, but since it was bytecode of just one object and not full valid pyc  program, it failed.

Comment: how is the object created? Can you share the code?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham: loaded using `marshal` from binary string created in suspicious way, including zlib compress and base64 encode

Comment: have a look here http://srossross.github.io/Meta/html/modules/meta/decompile.html